# Android Eclipse has lost context sensitive assistance

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

It was working before but then all of a sudden context sensitive help showing method names for example no long appear?  What could have changed?  I suppose if I create another workspace it will all work again but I hate to do that every time something like this happens.

If I do

```
  myObject.   // nothing appears here any more.  It was working yesterday.
```

What Eclipse does is show an error on the line as I type it in.

Comment: May be a silly question, but have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Yep.  Tried the restart its not working.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after updating my eclipse. This fix is fairly simple.

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors
```

Change "When mouse moved into hover:" to Enrich Immediately & click Apply, OK.

Comment: I am getting a description of the class, but I'm not getting the methods.

Comment: It did not work. looks like only thing that will save this project is to create a new workspace!

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you running? Also, see if the other 'Hover' preferences became messed up. Make sure the checkboxes are set as you wish.