# How can I reset eclipse to default settings?

Tags: eclipse

One of the top reasons I use an IDE editor is to get context information about the classes I am working on.  Right now I have lost the java method context information, and have no idea where to reset it? I see an error displayed by eclipse on the line number as I am typing instead of the list of methods and signatures.

```
 Android Developer Tools

 Build: v22.0.4-741630

 This product includes Eclipse Platform, JDT, CDT, EMF, GEF and WTP,
 all of which are Copyright (c) Eclipse contributors and others.
 Visit http://eclipse.org/
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Eclipse. Lost context sensitive hlp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067447/android-eclipse-lost-context-sensitive-hlp)

Comment: Not really. I want to know how to reset eclipse to default values regardless of the problem. but I'll change the title.

Comment: Right, that's why I say it's a duplicate of your two-hour-old question, since it states, "Is there no reset option with eclipse?" Honestly, though, this one is less of a question and more of a rant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, Eclipse can be a pain, as almost any IDE can. Please remain factual, however.

Switching to a new workspace should help you. Eclipse has almost no settings that are stored outside your workspace.

Comment: "Eclipse team where are you? This This kind of madness will have more of us switching over to an intelligent ide." That. Before you edited it out. Well done.

Comment: Also, please refrain from trying to edit out stuff from my response simply because you do not like it. In order not to escalate things further, this is my final post in this thread.

Comment: I am going to mark this as answered because I think the new workspace is currently the only option.

Comment: no need to switch to new workspace, deleting .metadata folder from existing workspace will work

Answer (score 33):

Delete the `.metadata` folder in your workspace.

Answer (score 8):

You can reset settings for eclipse by deleting .metadata folder from your current workspace.

This will however remove all projects from your **project explorer NOT workspace.** So dont worry your projects have not gone anywhere.

You can import projects from your workspace like this :
just make sure that you **uncheck** "Copy project into workspace".

[image: import]
Have a look here :
[image: import project in eclipse]

Comment: Importing existing project has been changed since the described version. Now select _File > Import ... > General > Projects from Foldes or Archive_.

Answer (score 1):

All the setting are stored in **.metadata file** in your workspace delete this and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

no need to set default if u are facing issues with some windows and u close it accidently , just go to windows and click on show views and the rest will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

Type in Quick access section: reset
and tap on it.
DONE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just tried this, and it worked. What this means is that, there is a Quick Access search box, which is generally visible in the UI, type reset in this box, and select reset perspective. It will reset to default.

The perspective rearrangement issue was solved using this trick when using Eclipse Neon in Ubuntu, for me that is.